# vba Word create a variable with value of text between 2 cursor points

Tags: vba, ms-word, cursor-position

We are trying to revise rtf docs that are created by Molecular Device software.
Here is an example of part of one of these documents:

Protocol 'C:\ALL USERS\Params\Current\2017 Opto Params\0  VoltageClampContinuous.pro' opened.
 C:\ALL USERS\Alan\2018_07_11\2018_07_11_0000.abf started at 00:19:48 stopwatch time.

So for right now - all I am trying to do is automatically find the experiment date (in this case = "2018_07_11_")
My sub so far can find the correct cursor positions but how do I select the text between 2 cursor positions?

Below is what I have the CursorPosition statement is of course wrong - this is what I am looking to correct.

```
Sub FindfilenameDate()

    txt_prior_to_expDate = "\"
    txt_after_expDate = "0000"
    With ActiveDocument.Content.Find
            .Text = txt_after_expDate
            .Forward = True
            .Execute
            If .Found = True Then
                .Parent.Select
                Set after_rng = Selection.Range
                expDateEnd_cursorPos = after_rng.Start - 1
                Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory, Extend:=wdExtend
                With Selection.Find
                    .Text = txt_prior_to_expDate
                    .Forward = False
                    .Execute
                    If .Found = True Then
                        .Parent.Select
                        Set charBefore_expDate = Selection.Range
                        expDateStart_cursorPos = charBefore_expDate.Start + 1
                    End If
                End With
            End If
    End With
   'expDate = CursorPosition(expDateStart_cursorPos, expDateEnd_cursorPos)
'MsgBox ("expDate = " & expDate) 'DELETEMSGBOX
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

The trick to something like this is to work with multiple `Range` objects. My personal preference is to declare a Range for each separate thing to be worked with, rather than trying to figure out the minimum and re-use a Range - at least for the initial code and testing purposes.

For this task, then, I use four Ranges: 1) For the original search, 2) for the end of the "cursor position" that's wanted, 3) For the second search, 4) for the final "cursor position".

The other important concepts are how to "collapse" a Range and how to "copy" one.

Collapsing a Range is like pressing the right- or left-arrow key with a selection, so that it is a "point" and doesn't contain anything. A Range can be collapsed to its start or end position.

Copying a Range (setting one Range to another) needs to be done using the `Duplicate` property so that the copy is independent of the original. Otherwise, when one is changed the other changes, as well.

```
Sub FindfilenameDate()
    Dim rngFind As Word.Range, rngBefore As Word.Range
    Dim rngAfter As Word.Range, rngFound As Word.Range

    txt_prior_to_expDate = "\"
    txt_after_expDate = "0000"
    Set rngFind = ActiveDocument.content
    With rngFind.Find
            .Text = txt_after_expDate
            .Forward = True
            .Execute
            If .found = True Then

                Set rngAfter = rngFind.Duplicate
                rngAfter.Collapse wdCollapseStart
                Set rngBefore = rngFind.Duplicate
                rngBefore.Collapse wdCollapseStart
                With rngBefore.Find
                    .Text = txt_prior_to_expDate
                    .Forward = False
                    .Execute
                    If .found = True Then
                        Set rngFound = rngBefore.Duplicate
                        rngFound.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
                        rngFound.End = rngAfter.Start
                        'rngFound.Select
                    End If
                End With
            End If
    End With
   'expDate = CursorPosition(expDateStart_cursorPos, expDateEnd_cursorPos)
    MsgBox ("expDate = " & rngFound.Text) 'DELETEMSGBOX
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Though it's not apparent why you're after the date string ending in _0000 rather than the date that is the parent folder name, a much simpler approach for a single date would be:

```
Sub Demo()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With ActiveDocument.Range
  With .Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Text = "[0-9]{4}_[0-9]{2}_[0-9]{2}_0000"
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
    .Format = False
    .MatchWildcards = True
    .Execute
  End With
  If .Find.Found = True Then MsgBox "expDate = " & Split(.Text, "_0000")(0)
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

And, for all such dates in a document:

```
Sub Demo()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With ActiveDocument.Range
  With .Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Text = "[0-9]{4}_[0-9]{2}_[0-9]{2}_0000"
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
    .Format = False
    .MatchWildcards = True
    .Execute
  End With
  Do While .Find.Found = True
    MsgBox "expDate = " & Split(.Text, "_0000")(0)
    .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
    .Find.Execute
  Loop
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```